# Connect Samsung Galaxy note 7 to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to connect my SAMSUNG Note 7 to Android studio 2.1, I activate the 'Developer options'. I have connected the phone to the PC but I am not able to see my device in the `Connected Devices` options.
here are the images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable `USB debugging` in the `Developer Options` menu. If that doesn't work download the drivers for the device.

Answer (score 0):

- Driver is not necessary in this case, because different user interface representation option in tab compare to mobile.
- Settings > About device > Software info > Build number   //click for seven time, -
- Developer options - will get created in
- Settings > Developer options > enable/Usb debugging > .Worked for Samsung galaxy J Max tab.